# Best approach to pull max value from a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table where the details of check-in activity performed by all the users is captured. Below is the structure with sample data.

Table Name: check_in

```
+-----------+--------------------+---------------------+
|   id      |       user_id      |      time           |
+-----------+--------------------+---------------------+
|   1       |       10001        | 2016-04-02 12:04:02 |
|   2       |       10001        | 2016-04-02 11:04:02 |
|   3       |       10002        | 2016-10-27 23:56:17 |
|   4       |       10001        | 2016-04-02 10:04:02 |
|   5       |       10002        | 2016-10-27 22:56:17 |
|   6       |       10002        | 2016-10-27 21:56:17 |
+-----------+--------------------+---------------------+
```

On the dashboard, I have to display each user and at what time was their latest check-in activity performed (Sample dashboard view shown below).

> User 1's last check-in was at 2016-04-02 12:04:02
>
> User 2's last check-in was at 2016-10-27 23:56:17

What is the best and efficient way to write the query to pull this data?
I have written below query, but it is taking 5-8 seconds to complete the execution. **Note: This table has hundreds of thousands of rows.**

```
select user_id, max(time) as last_check_in_at from check_in group by user_id
```

Comment: Do you have an indexes on `user_id` and `time`?

Comment: @quasoft : Nope

Comment: Post the table definition

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL query look optimized to me.

The reason for it being slow is probably that you do not have indexes on `user_id` and `time` columns.

Try adding the following indexes to your table:

```
ALTER TABLE `check_in` ADD INDEX `user_id` (`user_id`)
ALTER TABLE `check_in` ADD INDEX `time` (`time`)
```

and then execute your SQL query again to see if it makes a difference.

The indexes should allow the SQL engine to quickly group the relevant records by `user_id` and also quickly determine the maximum `time`.

Indexes will also help to quickly sort data by `time` (as suggested by Rajesh)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `order by`
Note:- please don't use `time` as a column name because may be it should be **reserved keywords** in any language

```
  select chk.user_id user_id, chk.time as last_check_in_at from   
    check_in chk group by chk.user_id ORDER BY chk.time
```

Comment: While time is a keyword it is not a reserved name.

Comment: @Rajesh, using order by doesn't provide max time of each user. Can you relook at your query once?
Also, execution time is same, 5-8 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use order by in query.

Please try this query

```
select `user_id`,`time` as last_check_in_at from check_in group by user_id order by `time` DESC
```

It works for me.